# Display 404 page if user is not authenticated django

Tags: django

I'm using django in my page. It's awesome. But I've little bit different requirements.
I want to display 404 for restricted page instead for redirecting user to login page. If user is not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

you can user login required mixins

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
   ....
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator